# EF core NullReferenceException accessing related entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda, asp.net-core

How do you update a subtable value with Lambda EF core.

```
var UpdatePercentage = _context.TaskOverview.Single(c => c.Id == 100);
UpdatePercentage.Completedpercentage = 30;
UpdatePercentage.TaskSubInfo.Content1 = "Some value";

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I get NullReferenceException error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: on which of your three lines do you get your exception: is your _context null? or is UpdatePercentage.CompletedPercentage null? Or perhaps UpdatePercentage.TaskSubInfo is null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are getting the `NullReferenceException` on the related `Entity` TaskSubInfo.

`EntityFramework` doesnt load related `Entity` by default but **[you have to do it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)**

```
var UpdatePercentage = _context.TaskOverview
                            .Include(to => to.TaskSubInfo)
                            .Single(c => c.Id == 100);

UpdatePercentage?.Completedpercentage = 30;
UpdatePercentage?.TaskSubInfo.Content1 = "Some value";

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var UpdatePercentage = _context.TaskOverview.Include("TaskSubInfo").Single(c => c.Id == 100);
```